# What is the advantage of FTS over custom solution?

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, arabic

I have a biggish database ~32mb which has lots of text in 4 languages. Including Arabic and Urdu. I need to search this text in the most efficient way (speed & size).

I am considering FTS, and trying to find out how to implement it. Right now I am reading http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_2 about it.

It seems to me, an FTS table is just like a normal table used to index all the different words. So my questions are:

1) If to populate FTS I have to do all the inserts myself, then why not make my own indexed word table, what is the difference?

Answer : Yes there are many advantages, many built in functions that help. For example with ranking etc, searching of stems and the transparent nature of how it all works in android makes the FTS approach more appealing.

2) On the google docs I read its a virtual in memory table, now this would be massive right... but it doesnt mention this on the SQLite website. So which is it?

3) Is there an easy way to generate all the different words from my columns?

4) Will the FTS handle arabic words properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. FTS allows for fast searching of *words*; normal indexes only allow to search for entire values or for the beginning of the value.
   If you table has only one word in each field, using FTS does not make sense.
2. FTS is a virtual table, but not an in-memory table.
3. You can get individual terms from the full-text index with the [fts4aux table](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#fts4aux).
4. The default [tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer) works only with ASCII text.
   You have to test whether the ICU or UNICODE61 tokenizers work with your data.

Comment: UNICODE61 does not handle arabic and is really meant for latin characters and ICU is not compiled as part of any android sqlite implementations I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) If to populate FTS I have to do all the inserts myself, then why
>   not make my own indexed word table, what is the difference?

Using your own indexed word table, you would have parse `words` in `sentences`. You would then need a table for sentences and another to words. And you should do this efficiently.

> 2) On the google docs I read its a virtual in memory table, now this
>   would be massive right... but it doesnt mention this on the SQLite
>   website. So which is it?

Don't understand your question. Data is handled via virtual table extension, however back storage is done in database (FTS4 creates 5 tables for each virtual table). Check this:

```
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE docs USING fts4();
sqlite> .schema
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE docs USING fts4();
CREATE TABLE 'docs_content'(docid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'content');
CREATE TABLE 'docs_segments'(blockid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, block BLOB);
CREATE TABLE 'docs_segdir'(level INTEGER,idx INTEGER,start_block INTEGER,leaves_
end_block INTEGER,end_block INTEGER,root BLOB,PRIMARY KEY(level, idx));
CREATE TABLE 'docs_docsize'(docid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, size BLOB);
CREATE TABLE 'docs_stat'(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value BLOB);
sqlite>
```

> 3) Is there an easy way to generate all the different words from my
>   columns?

For sure. But that's not easy. That's what FTS does.

> 4) Will the FTS handle arabic words properly?

I'm not sure. Does arabic languages uses ICU word boundaries? From [Tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer):

> The ICU tokenizer implementation is very simple. It splits the input
>   text according to the ICU rules for finding word boundaries and
>   discards any tokens that consist entirely of white-space. This may be
>   suitable for some applications in some locales, but not all. If more
>   complex processing is required, for example to implement stemming or
>   discard punctuation, this can be done by creating a tokenizer
>   implementation that uses the ICU tokenizer as part of its
>   implementation.

Comment: I found this http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/ArabicShaping.html does this mean ICU supports arabic?

Comment: I'm not expert on UNICODE language support. Regard nr 4 from @CL answer.